# How could I abort and apply space when company suggests completion?

Tags: company

While I am typing `company` shows suggestons. When I press space I want to abort suggestions and apply space, but instead it only does abort. Hence I need to press two times space to apply space.

**[Q]** How could I abort and apply space when company suggests completion?

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(setq company-auto-complete t)

(with-eval-after-load "company"
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-p") #'company-select-previous-or-abort)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-n") #'company-select-next-or-abort)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-h") #'backward-delete-char)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd ".") #'company-abort)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "SPC") #'company-abort)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-f") #'company-abort)
  )

(eval-after-load 'company
  '(progn
     (define-key company-active-map (kbd "TAB") 'company-complete-common-or-cycle)
     (define-key company-active-map (kbd "<tab>") 'company-complete-common-or-cycle)))

(setq company-frontends
      '(company-pseudo-tooltip-unless-just-one-frontend
        company-preview-frontend
        company-echo-metadata-frontend))

(setq company-auto-complete t)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-k") 'company-complete)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite an ugly (and untested) suggestion:

1. Define an ad-hoc function:

```lisp
(defun company-abort-and-insert-space ()
  (interactive)
  (company-abort)
  (insert " "))
```

2. Replace

```lisp
(define-key company-active-map (kbd "SPC") #'company-abort)
```

by

```lisp
(define-key company-active-map (kbd "SPC") #'company-abort-and-insert-space)
```

in your `init.el` file.